# Switch camera icon on left or right side?

Tags: usability, mobile-application, accessibility, alignment, camera

I'm building a custom snap-photo flow in between another flow in my App.
So here I have an interesting dilemma.

**Should the Selfie/Rear cam toggle icon be on the left or right side and why?** *[image below]*

Data points

1. Majority of my users are RIGHT handed
2. Majority are iOS users
3. Default iOS camera app has it on RIGHT side
4. Instagram & Whatsapp has it on RIGHT side
5. But, Google camera app has it on LEFT side

[image]

Comment: I would put it on the right because it gives additional primacy to the main take photo button that way.

Comment: Thats a good point. Thanks @MikePoole

Comment: Is putting it on the left on Android, and on the right on iOS an option?

Comment: That can be done. But a question will arise: "why not right in android?" there are many android apps as well as default android camera apps that have it on right.

Answer (score 2):

If these two are the only options available on the action bar of your app, I would suggest that you leave the Toggle option at the right. Considering your datapoints this would be the best option to go ahead with. As the user wouldn't have to stretch out his thumb to the other end on the screen just to opt for the only other option.

Also, like in generic camera apps, double tap on the screen could toggle the camera as well.

Edit: This could be useful as well. Eliminates the issue of having it either on the right or left.
[image]

Comment: Have considered the fact that folding and reaching the nearest corner is also not easy. Users feel the uneasiness. The heatmap in this area appears to be red.

Comment: I like the edit. Thanks @Harsh for coming back with new ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I am right handed person and my brother is left handed but we both prefer on right side as most effective used feature options are available on right side only (End user perspective)

> One more option is to add this option on top right corner on
>   navigation bar to save extra space.

[image]

Comment: Wow, as a user, that would be a really annoying placement of two related buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if there are only two buttons in the action bar, it is better to leave the camera switch on the left side because in this case, you reduce the probability that the button is positioned under the thumb of the right hand and the user will notice it at first glance, You also prevent from accidentally touching this button.

Answer (score 0):

This bottom bar is quite high so there is enough space to satisfy righties and lefties IMO

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it should be on right side because there is equal advantage for both, switch and snap button. as majority of the users are right handed so it would be easy for them to use it